# $_SESSION storage fails for direct assignment of array

Tags: session, php

Today I have come to very strange situation.
I was trying to store `$_POST` data in to `$_SESSION`. So first I did

```
$data = $db->FilterParameters($_POST);
// method 1
$_SESSION['default']['car_rental'] = $data;
```

So the page gets loaded and session data gets saved properly. When I print them, they were ok.
But as soon as I go to other page, they gets destroyed.
Then I tried

```
// method 2
foreach ($data as $k => $v){

    $_SESSION['default']['car_rental'][$k] = $v;
}
```

and It worked fine when I jumped to second page. and session data was maintained.
I have already put `session_start()` as the first line in the boht pages.

Why this happened? What was wrong? I could not figure out.

Comment: Did you put `session_start();` on top of both files?

Comment: I have updated question. Yes buddy, i put.

Comment: is it possible that $_POST array is not serializable, due to its recursive references, perhaps? are you copying entire $_POST into $data or just needed items?

Comment: I am copying entire `$_POST` in `$data`, but my `$_POST` itself is single dimension and not multi. I just making `$_SESSION` as multidimensional by storing `$_POST` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing any kind of check that `$_POST` is populated? If not it will overwrite your session values with an empty array, using your first method.

The foreach approach knows when an array is empty and doesn't execute, which means the previously assigned values remain in the session.

Here's some code to highlight what's happening:

```
<?php

session_start();
header("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n");

// method one
$_POST = array('test' => true); // dummy post
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST; // assign
$_POST = array(); // clear post
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST; // assign
print_r($_SESSION); // print (gives empty array)

// method two
$_POST = array('test' => true); // dummy post
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) $_SESSION['data'][$k] = $v; // assign
$_POST = array(); // clear post
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) $_SESSION['data'][$k] = $v; // assign, does nothing
print_r($_SESSION); // print (gives populated array, foreach doesn't execute)
```

Comment: Ya I completely agree with you, but that is only when `$_POST` gets reset some how, I have added form validation and so its impossible that `$_POST` to be blank or empty, it gets populated every time.

Comment: @RajanRawal Can you show us the entire file? It could be to do with something we can't see

Comment: i really appreciate for you concern, but as per company rules I can not share file. Otherwise I create a problem for me. I know there is nothing big in it, but even. Right now its working  with for loop, so I continue with that one. Thanks one again

Answer (score 0):

You have to have `session_start();` on top of both files. If that function is not called then your `$_SESSION[]` is just another array, not the `SESSION` super global and hence you cannot use share it between 2 pages.

Comment: Yes i put, i did not change anything other than just using `foreach()` loop, and then it started working fine